# How to determine value of text box in ASP MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to access the value of a text box within the same View? For example, in my view I have the following text box

```
@Html.TextBox("searchValue", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string, new { placeholder = "Search" })
```

If a user enters a value, then hits submit, the page will send that search criteria to the controller, query the database based on the criteria, and then display the results back in the view. When the view is rendered again, the text stays in the search box and the tag is rendered

```
<input id="searchValue" name="searchValue" placeholder="Search" type="text" value="what i just typed in here" />
```

is there a way for an ASP MVC 3 view to access the `value` of that text box? I want to create a condition similar to

```
    @if (searchValue.hasValue())
    {
        do something in here
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are u trying to do in the condition ?

Comment: Trying to add content to the page based on whether that text box has a value or not

Comment: can u do it in JQuery ? by checking `$('#searchValue').Val()` and then Ajax post/Get if required ?

Comment: ya I would recommend doing it with javascript since that code is meant to be executed on client side. Can you please be more specific on what you want to do with the text on the box? The text you want to show is something you need to fetch from your data or is it defined by default?

Comment: It's a link to the index page of another controller. Basically if the text box has a value, then the link should be displayed. If no value, no link.

Comment: That link may have some id and `$('#Linkid').show` will do that job in case $('#textboxid').val() is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is rendered synchronously, when the page first loads. All Razor expressions are evaluated when the page renders, so what you get back is static HTML. You can't use that to track subsequent changes to form values - only to carry out logic based on their initial values for the current response.

You need to use Javascript. Supposing you have a link with an `id` of `myLink`. Style it to `display:none;` by default. Then, with jQuery, you can do the following:

```
<input id="searchValue" name="searchValue" ... />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#searchValue').change(function (){
         if($('#searchValue').val().length > 0) {
             $('#myLink').show();
         } else {
             $('#myLink').hide();
         }
    });
</script>
```

If you need more complex logic, you could switch out the link with a partial view and update it with AJAX calls.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood, but it looks like you are populating the searchbox with `ViewBag.CurrentFilter` and then "When the view is rendered again, the text stays in the search box" as "value="what i just typed in here"

Which sounds to me like you already know what the search text is, so why do you need to read the value of the textbox? Why wouldn't the logic be

```
@if (`ViewBag.CurrentFilter` hasSomeValue)
{
    do something in here
}
```

Sorry in advance if I missed the point.

Comment: I think the question relates to dynamically hiding and showing content based on the *current value of the textbox as it changes*, for which he needs jQuery.